# c++11 initializer_list doesn't work for literal constant value of embedded object?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, aggregate-initialization

I've got a simple program in c++11:

```
struct A{
    int i;
    struct B{
        int i;
        int j;
    };
} a = {2, {3, 4}};
```

g++-7 compiles and gives error:

```
error: too many initializers for 'A'
 }a={2,{3,4}};
            ^
```

I just wonder how can I declare an object of A using literal constants, how to fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your type `A` only contains a single data member (of type `int`), you can have at most one element in your initializer:

```
struct A{
    int i;
    struct B{
        int i;
        int j;
    };
} a = {2};   // OK, a.i == 2
```

(The fact that `A` also contains a type member (`A::B`) is immaterial to the creation of objects of type `A`.)

Comment: Great answer. So had OP declared `struct B { ... } b;` and named a member too, their code would work, so it's likely they just forgot to declare a member of type `B`

Comment: Yes, that little `} b;` would have made all the difference as well.

Comment: That's why we generally frown on type definitions *inside* variable/member declarations! It's overly cute for no purpose other than to confuse everyone. That sort of style is at best appropriate for pub quizzes, but not for code that communicates between humans.